# Is it possible to pre-download a YouTube video to view it later?

Tags: wi-fi, youtube

[Is it possible to pre-download a YouTube video to view it later offline?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39128/is-it-possible-to-pre-download-a-youtube-video-to-view-it-later-offline?newreg=b4e8b45c58734eafbba31fb5d4576ff7) I know this is a duplicate, but the functionality has been removed for a year, and no (automatic) alternatives to the problem.

So here is the problem I take the train 2 hours everyday, and I dont have Wifi and 3G would just have its download limit busted in a day.

Si I would like to have my 'Watch Later' playlist (or could be another playlist) automatically downloaded to my phone when I have WiFi so I can watch it later, when I have no network.

The current solutions would be to manually download every video, then transfer them to my phone. Any app that does it automatically?

Comment: It seems pressing a watch later button is as much work as pressing a download button. Or do you want an auto-generated playlist too? Edit: I just realized you don't download with an app but with your desktop!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pre-download a YouTube video to view it later offline?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39128/is-it-possible-to-pre-download-a-youtube-video-to-view-it-later-offline). Since there's no in-app feature, the rest of the answers on the dupe are also applicable to this question.

Comment: Youtube's [help on the subject](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7381437?hl=en) - looks like this may be a YouTube premium feature now.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to download Youtube Go from playstore, it has the ability to download the video you want and watch it wherever you are. This works offline too and when you prompt the download you can set the quality of the video you want to download

Take a look at here

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.youtube.mango&hl=en_US

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to download the videos through the YouTube app: yes, you can!

YouTube has that functionality present internally at the moment, so no need for third party apps.

<sub>Screenshots (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

[image: First hit the download button here] [image: And you can find it here once downloaded]

Comment: You forgot to mention that this option is only available to specific videos and offline storage of videos are limited to a specific period of time.

Comment: Yes...its true!! good thing you pointed out @Lucky!! and again...this affects your internal storage space

Comment: Dont seem to have that option. What version of the YT app do you have?

Comment: my app version is the latest available on the playstore **10.43.60**

Answer (score 0):

You can also open the youtube video you'd like to download in your browser and then add "dlv" in front of youtube in the URL so that it becomes dlvyoutube.com

Not sure how much more smooth this will be compared to working on your computer + transfer if you want to download several videos..